# How to completely stop a Thread which includes a buffered reader?

Tags: java, multithreading

It's a "guess the number in 10 seconds game", looping until the user wants the program to stop (the game restarts indefinitely, or until the user types "exit").
The problem is, if a round is failed (time out), and then the user prints the correct answer, the game says it's won. That means, the thread of the last game (round) was not interrupted. Here are the classes:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Initializer extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int x = (abs(rand.nextInt())) % 101;
        GameEngine gameEngine = new GameEngine(x);
        gameEngine.start();
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                wait(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Initializer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        if (gameEngine.isAlive()) {
            gameEngine.interrupt();
            System.out.println("Time is up! The number was " + x);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Initializer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}



public class GameEngine extends Thread {

    private final int valueToGuess;

    public GameEngine(int x) {
        this.valueToGuess = x;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("ConvertToTryWithResources")
    public synchronized void run() {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true) {
            try {
                int x;
                String line = br.readLine();
                if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) System.exit(0);
                try {
                    x = Integer.parseInt(line);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a number!");
                    continue;
                }
                if (x < valueToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("Too low!");
                }
                if (x > valueToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("Too high!!");
                }
                if (x == valueToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("You won!");
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GameEngine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GameEngine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Guess the number!");
        Initializer counter = new Initializer();
        counter.start();
        while (true) {
            if(counter.isAlive()) continue;
            System.out.println("Game starts in:");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("5");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("4");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("3");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("2");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("1");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Guess the number!");
            counter = new Initializer();
            counter.start();
        }
    }
}
```

So if I run it, considering the value to guess to be 50, and I fail the round, when the next round starts, if I type 50, I get "You won!" from the last round, then "Wrong" from the current round. I chose BufferedReader over Scanner because I read that Scanner.nextLine() is blocking the thread, making it uninterruptable, while BufferedReader does not block it. The problem must be when I notify the Initializer Thread to interrupt the GameEngine Thread. I'm new to multithreading so it must be a mistake with all those synchronized or wait/notify instructions. Any help please?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `gameEngine.wait(10000);`? You're waiting and notifying on different objects...

Comment: The Initializer should wait for 10 seconds, and be notified by GameEngine if it's won, otherwise, after those 10 seconds, the Initializer should interrupt GameEngine. So I guess no, Initializer waits 10 seconds to be notified, otherwise it stops GameEngine.

Comment: `this.notifyAll();` This won't notify anything because nothing is waiting on a GameEngine object.

Comment: @1000ml You are right. But since the OP is waiting for set period of time, it's equivalent to a call to `sleep` for 10 seconds with the difference being that the locks will be released (which is kind of pointless anyway). So the `wait` call without a corresponding `notify` is still fine.

Comment: @1000ml I'm new to the multithreading stuff. How can I notify the Initializer that GameEngine is finished?

Comment: Why are you extending Thread when you should be implementing Runnable? Or better still why not use executors as well as some of the newer concurrency constructs?

Comment: @Andrew Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The program is not working the way you expect it to is primarily because of your understanding of how `Thread.interupt` works. Consider the following two lines of code :

```
   if (gameEngine.isAlive()) {
        gameEngine.interrupt();
        System.out.println("Time is up! The number was " + x);
   }
```

Your expectation is that just by calling `interupt`, you will be halting the `GameEngine` thread on which `interrupt` is called. This is not true. The `interrupt` method will only update the state of the `Thread` as interrupted. An `InterruptedException` will then be thrown by any method that monitors the interrupt state of the `Thread`.

Since you don't call any such method in your `GameEngine` thread, an `InterruptedException` will never be thrown. Try adding a method that monitors the interrupt state (such as `sleep`) inside the `run` method of `GameEngine` and you will have the desired effect of an `InterruptedException` being thrown.

**Sidenote :** Always prefer composition over inheritance. Don't extend from `Thread` unless you want to modify the way `Thread` class performs some functionality. Implement `Runnable` instead.

Comment: Where exactly should I add such a method so it won't interfere with the code? I have an infinite loop there where I constantly read from keyboard, wouldn't a sleep() basically pause it?

Comment: @Andrew There was a flaw in your understanding of how the `interrupt` method works which lead you to design your code this way. The way your code stands, it will require a couple of more tweaks that won't fit in the comments section and would also make your question susceptible to being closed as *Too Broad*

Comment: I see. Thank you for your time. Gonna read some more about this matter.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem behind it's not working is your wrong understanding about `Thread.interrupt` method. So, Let's talk about it.

When you call `interrupt` on any thread object, an internal flag known as *interrupt* status is set. You can read about it more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).   So when you are calling `gameEngine.interrupt();` interrupt status flag gets set, but you are not checking the status of interrupt flag anywhere in your code. So your thread executes as normally it would do.

Now, when it reaches `String line = br.readLine();` line. It waits for the user input and when user enters the correct answer you just displayed, it matches with the `if (x == valueToGuess)` condition and your loop terminates due to `break` inside that if condition.

So what you need is a way to check whether the interrupt flag is set or not and that you can check using [Thread.interrupted()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) or [thread.isInterrupted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted()) method.

The main difference between these two the methods is that, `Thread.interrupted()` method is static method and by default it checks for the current thread and it will clear the `interrupt` status flag. Whereas `thread.isInterrupted()` is an instance method and can be called on an instance of thread to check whether it is interrupted or not. It will not clear the `interrupt` status flag.

Now, solution to your problem. 
`String line = br.readLine();` is the only blocking call in your code. So add the following line after it.

So it would be something like

```
String line = br.readLine();
// This will check the interrupt status flag and if set will clear it. So next call will return false.  
if (Thread.interrupted()) {  
    break;
}
```

or

```
String line = br.readLine();
// This will check the interrupt status flag and will not clear it, so any following call will also return true.
if (this.isInterrupted()) {    // or just if (isInterrupted()) as you are extending the Thread class. 
    break;
}
```

Hope it helps.